# Booting into Windows after 14.04 Install (dualboot)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader

So I just finished installing Ubuntu 14.04! But the bootloader does not seem to work since I just boot into Windows 8.1 automatically. I have tried running the boot repair app without success. The weird thing is that I can reach the bootloader by going to my boot devices in the BIOS and select ubuntu and then I get to the bootloader screen and select Ubuntu and then it boots successfully into my newly installed version of Ubuntu.

Do any of you guys have any clue how to fix this so that the bootloader menu shows up on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I would use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). It provides a pretty simple, handy gui and it makes configuring your bootloader a snap...

Good luck, hope it helps.

Comment: I tried EasyBCD and I get two options on startup, one for Windows and one for Ubuntu, but the Ubuntu leads to a page where it says "Windows could not be booted correctly..." Maybe I did the EasyBCD configuration wrong?

Comment: Here is a snappy tutorial... http://shishtpal.blogspot.com/2013/09/all-about-easybcd-small-tutorial.html Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a BIOS new enough that it is using EFI / UEFI boot for Windows do you? That would skip going to the disk for the boot loader and just load Windows.